# Where is the SequenceRange from the walk-method from ExtendedDataModel defined?

Tags: ajax4jsf

The `ExtendedDataModel` from ajax4jsf uses a method called `walk`, looking like this:

```
public void walk(FacesContext ctx, DataVisitor dv, Range range, Object argument){}
```

This method is called several times in my application. Some topics on internet seem to say that it the latter is defined by the `rows="x"` in the xhtml. However, for me `range` is always defined as `0 (firstRow)` - `-1 (getRows)`.

So I was wondering where this `range` is defined, so I can figure out why the wrong parameters are passed to it. Debugging and googling hasn't helped me so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range represents visible part of data displayed in table. If you have paginator, then paginator display which page (= from which row to which row) data is presented.

Problem can be in incorrect value of `rows` attribute of data table (for example `rows` attribute is missing).

Other place can be in incorrect implementation of data model. Object of data model class can be used as storage for data displayed in `rich:dataTable`.

**Real example:**

```
public class VSDataModel<RecordType> extends ExtendedDataModel<RecordType> implements Arrangeable {

    private final FetchList<RecordType> list;

    @Override
    public void walk(FacesContext ctx, DataVisitor visitor, Range range, Object obj) {
        try {
            int firstRow = ((SequenceRange) range).getFirstRow();
            int numberOfRows = ((SequenceRange) range).getRows();
            if(list == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Underlying list is null!");
            }
            if(list.getList() == null || firstRow != list.getFirstRow()) {
                list.fetch(firstRow, numberOfRows);
            }
            for (RecordType elem : list.getList()) {
                visitor.process(ctx, list.getPK(elem), obj);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

It is used in Java `private VSDataModel<Record> dependentList;` and html 
`<rich:dataTable value="#{bean.dependentList}" rows="#{referenceData.recordsPerPage}">`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have experimented quite a bit and got everything working (I will post an answer to my other question as well). I am still wondering when the walk method is called exactly; I noticed it is called a couple of times, but I'm not sure exactly when. Could you, if you know, elaborate on it a bit?
I feel like it is called each time the tabel is drawn, but that doesn't explain why it is called three times in quick succession.

Comment: Yes, RichFaces called it each times dataTable is re-drawn.